# Getting the error while trying to fetch data entered into edit text fields in alert dialog, I have used Kotlin as the language

Tags: kotlin, android-layout, android-alertdialog

```
val mDialogView =
            LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.enterupdateaddresslayout, null)
        //AlertDialogBuilder
        val mBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setView(mDialogView)
            .setTitle("Update Delivery Address")
        //show Dialog
        val mAlertDialog = mBuilder.show()

        //click on SAVE Button
        mDialogView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.popUpUpdateSaveButton).setOnClickListener {
            //get text from Edit Texts of alert layout
            val houseNo =
                mDialogView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.popUpHouseNumber).text
            Log.d("House Number", "$houseNo")
```

I am trying to get the data entered into the EditText into the houseNo variable.
when ever that line of code executes, error is being displayed or session is getting logged out.

Below is the enterupdateaddresslayout layout xml code.

I have tried all the tricks but none are working.
Can anyone please help?
The buttons are working fine, it is only the issue with the Edit Text fields.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cardViewPopUp"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/popUpUpdateHouseNumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/enter_house_number"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/popUpUpdateStreetName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/popUpUpdateHouseNumber"
        android:hint="@string/enter_street_name"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/popUp_Update_City_Village"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/popUpUpdateStreetName"
        android:hint="@string/enter_city_village_name"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/popUp_Update_District"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/popUp_Update_City_Village"
        android:hint="@string/enter_district_name"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/popUp_Update_State"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/popUp_Update_District"
        android:hint="@string/enter_state_name"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/popUp_Update_PinCode"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/popUp_Update_State"
        android:hint="@string/enter_pincode"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/popUpUpdateSaveButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/popUp_Update_PinCode"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:text="@string/save"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/popUpUpdateCancelButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/popUp_Update_PinCode"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:text="@string/cancel"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: convert the houseNo value to toString() and try and also post the error log

Comment: I have tried with toString(), still it is giving error.
Below is the error:
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Comment: It seems that `mDialogView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.popUpHouseNumber)` just does not find anything and thus `.text` leads to an NPE.

Comment: Can you post the `enterupdateaddresslayout` layout?

Comment: @LucaPizzini I have added the .xml code for the layout.

Comment: @KarstenGabriel Actually the code execution stops the moment, compiler starts executing this line and the session is getting logged out.

Comment: As @KarstenGabriel suggested, there are no `EditText` with id `popUpHouseNumber` in the layout. That's the reason for the `NullPointerException`. You should change the line to `val houseNo = mDialogView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id. popUpUpdateHouseNumber).text`

Comment: Try using null-safe `?.text` instead of `.text`.

Comment: Thank you so much. The "id" was wrong. It's a silly mistake from my end.